# Creating a FixedUpdate in Typesript

Tags: typescript, game-engine

I'm working on a game-engine in typescript to learn some stuff. In Unity the way the fixed update works (in theory) is as follows:

```
 var physicsTimeSimulated = 0;
 var lastUpdateTime = 0;    

 while (Unity is Running)
 {
     while (physicsTimeSimulated < Time.time)
     {
         Engine.ExecutePhysicsStep();
         Engine.FixedUpdate(); // <-- sent to all objects
         physicsTimeSimulated += physicsTimeStep;
     }

     deltaTime = Time.time - lastUpdateTime;
     Engine.RenderFrame();
     Engine.Update(); // <-- sent to all objects
     lastUpdateTime = CurrentTime;

     // and repeat...
 }
```

What would be a good way to implement something like this in Typescript? The way I am doing the update function is as follows:

```
private fixedUpdateTiming: number = 1;
private lastUpdate:number = Date.now();

public Update(): void {
    while((Date.now() - this.lastUpdate) > this.fixedUpdateTiming){
      this.onAppFixedUpdate.dispatch();
      this.lastUpdate = Date.now();
    }

    this.onAppUpdate.dispatch();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.Update();
    });
  }
```

This way, there can be many updates per fixedupdate, but I can get only one fixedupdate per update.

Thanks in advance, Steenbrink

Comment: Did you try to use set Interval instead while  loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oké, nevermind, I am stupid. I will leave this here for reference.

The way I fixed it is as follows:

```
private fixedUpdateTiming: number = 20;
private physicsTimeSimulated:number = Date.now();
private _deltaTime: number = 0;
private lastUpdate: number = Date.now();

public Update(): void {

    while(this.physicsTimeSimulated < Date.now()){

      this.onAppFixedUpdate.dispatch();
      this.physicsTimeSimulated += this.fixedUpdateTiming;
    }

    this.onAppUpdate.dispatch();

    this._deltaTime = Date.now() - this.lastUpdate;
    this.lastUpdate = Date.now();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.Update();
    });
  }
```

Comment: this way if i applyForce in the fixedUpdate will the object be pushed more far away?